# how to copy a Thrust::host_vector<char> to a char*

Tags: cuda, nvidia, thrust

I'm trying my hands at CUDA thrust.
but the environment I'm working in needs me to copy the data at the end into a `char*` and not `thrust::host_vector<char>`
So my code right now looks something like below.

```
thrust::device_vector<unsigned int> sortindexDev(filesize);
thrust::host_vector<char>BWThost(filesize);
thrust::device_vector<char>BWTdev(filesize);
thrust::device_vector<char>inputDataDev(filesize);
  .
  .
  some code using thrust:: sort, thrust::transform, etc
  .
  .
  .
  .
BWThost = BWTdev;
```

After I have the copied data in `BWThost`.
I want to copy it to a `char*` for the need of my framework.
How do I do it?
Below code doesn't work.

```
for(int i = o; i < upper; i++) {
          charData[i] = BWThost[i]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`thrust::copy`](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__copying.html#ga6e123c4508ed48ce98e79f4679c1aac2), for example:

```
thrust::device_vector<char>BWTdev(filesize);
char *chardata = malloc(filesize);

thrust::copy(BWTdev.begin(), BWTdev.end(), &chardata[0]);
```

[disclaimer: written in browser, not compiled or tested, use at own risk]

This is copy directly from the `device_vector` to a host array without the need for any intermediate `host_vector` or explicitly host side loop.